# Why do asp:ContentPlaceHolders have opening and closing tags?

Tags: asp.net

I tried googling. (And MSDN-ing.)

I also tried putting text there, but it didn't have any effect.

EDIT: I mean: As opposed to being a one-tag element: `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... />`

Comment: Anybody care to explain the downvotes? Is the answer so obvious?

Comment: What is the problem you having? I am not quite sure what you struggling with!!! Normally it will be like <asp:Content ID="Content1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content> what is wrong with that?

Comment: Your question is pretty brief, and the meaning isn't immediately clear. Plus, this is answerable pretty easily with a search.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I don't have a problem using them. I just wondered why it's not a one-tag element like `Button`. (And see Esoteric's answer.)

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I searched. It didn't help. Thanks for the answer below.

Comment: @ispiro I know, just trying to offer what I think is the reasoning for the downvoting.

Comment: @ispiro: That is a bit odd expectation. When we think about the usage of content place holder normally some content (probably HTML) goes here. When you have something like <asp:ContentPlaceHolders ... /> where you expect the contents to be?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty In the [asp:Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.aspx) in the pages using this page as a master-page of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for specifying default content.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <!-- what's in here is the default content if the placeholder's content never gets set elsewhere-->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

[Here's an example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/multiple-contentplaceholders-and-default-content-vb).

Comment: Thanks. I thought it must have some use.

Answer (score 1):

IT doesn't have to have opening and closing. see below:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />
```

The above will work.

Comment: Thanks. +1. But VS adds the double-tagged type. So perhaps it can be of use somehow.